# Computer crashing at random

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure, computer-building

I've been having a "small-ish" issue where my computer randomly shuts down. Be it in the middle of a game or work etc, even on idle, it just crashes and reboots. no BSOD or anything. One minute it's on, the next of...well not off but restarting. Sometimes when I leave the pc and come back, I find it on the log-in screen.

If I had to put a number on how often it **used** to happen before, id says possibly once a month, 2 tops. Now it happens more often and it's hard to recreate the issues that are causing the restarts because usually, it happens while on idle.
I'd say 70% while on idle, 30% while on load.

I have asked around in other areas/friends etc and most people say that it's probably a power supply issue.

I've looked at threads like this one here for example [Computer Crashing Randomly](https://superuser.com/questions/218583/computer-crashing-randomly)

trying to see what other people in similar situations have done but to no avail.

As for what I've tried, I've:

- Re-installed windows thinking possibly of a driver issue(still same problem)
- I tried using a PSU calculator. This one seemed good. Had all my parts in there so, I tried it and I had more than enough power to burn.

> http://extreme.outervision.com/psucalculatorlite.jsp

- Tried tracking with CPUID HWMonitor (nothing I can see)
- Tried tracking with CPUID to try and catch it on specific loads (nothing)
- Tried re-plugging in the cables on the video card thinking maybe something loose??? (nothing)
- Ran MEMTEST to see if maybe it was the ram, I ran it for a few hours, and then overnight. All tests/passes were fine and had no issues.
- I took out the video card and used another from another rig I built (nothing)

**These are my sys specs (custom-built rig)(the important parts)**

1. CPU - I7 4770k
2. MOBO - Asus maximus 7 hero
3. GPU - GTX 780 [ 4gigs ]
4. GT 630 or something (smaller video card for side monitors)
5. PSU - CORSAIR 750w
6. RAM - I forget the type but some type of corsair [ 16 gigs ]
7. CORSAIR hydro cooling h100 i etc

I've tried to cover as much as possible. Any ideas on how I can resolve this or anything I may have missed?

Answer (score 1):

Have you de-dusted the rig inside? Dust is current-conductive (although very poor), so it may shorting you somewhere.

My best bet would be empty memory slots. Use canned air to clean them.
If you don't have any empty, remove your sticks and clean the slots as above.

While you're at it. take a look at PCI slots as well, and clean unused ones too.

If that won't help, retest components if you can. Swap PSU and HDDs and see if issue persists.

Last thing: are you sure it is random? Maybe all events are connected by some piece of equipment being accessed/woken up?

Comment: Howdy Ace. My system is SUPER clean. Im OCD when it comes to my system being clean. I've also tried seating/un-seating ram chips and testing one by one and didnt solve anything unfortunately because i couldnt recreate the issue. As for "am i sure its random, events connected etc" , I say random because most times, it happens on idle. and im on my computer A LOT.

Comment: Ok, with dust out the window (sort of, I don't know if you cleaned slots ;) let's tackle it further.
You said: "most times, it happens on idle. and im on my computer A LOT". That right there is sign it's not random... My suggestion would be to check system with bare config - disconnect every usb device you can but still have machine operable. See if that changes anything.

After this point I'd direct my attention to networking... Windows on idle may suspend some devices here and/or there...